# Carathéodory's extension theorem to extend CDF $F_X$ to a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification, cumulative-distribution-functions

Please help me add more details/corrections to **text in bold below**

1. Let $\mathcal{A} = \{ (a, b] : a \leq b \}$. $\mathcal{A} \subseteq
       2^\mathbb{R}$. This is a semiring or ring? **More details here** ...
2. Define a pre-measure $\mu : \mathcal{A} \mapsto [0, 1]$ by
   $$\mu\left( (a, b ] \right) = F_X(b) - F_X(a)$$
3. Consider the sequence $ \delta_i = (-i, i] \in \mathcal{A}$. Then,
   $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \delta_i = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu(\delta_i) < \infty$.

Then, **under some more conditions**, $\mu$ can be extended to a unique probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.